# Что такое "драбадан"?

Tags: этимология, значение-слов

Пожалуй, ни к чему в русском языке нет столько эпитетов, как к степени опьянения.

*Напиться можно **в: стельку, зюзю, дрова, хлам, дым, драбадан...***

И есть еще куча всяческих определений, которые мне сейчас и в голову не приходят.
Из всех перечисленных мне не понятен только "драбадан" (зюзя - если не ошибаюсь, - название свиньи).
*Так что же такое - **"драбадан"**, и почему **в него** можно напиться?*

Answer (score 2):

Жаргонное выражение *пьяный в драбадан* (сильно пьяный) первоначально произносилось "в дрЕбадан" и вполне может вести своё происхождение от наречия вдребезги или существительного дребедень. Скорее всего, их смешение и дало жизнь этому жаргонизму. Ср. : вдребезги пьяный и пьяный в драбадан.

Answer (score 2):

Дребедан, дробадан, драбадан и проч.  -  от дребедень: околесина, чушь, бессвязная речь и т.п. Пьяный в дребедень - напившийся до бессвязной речи.

При чем тут "дребезги" - не совсем понимаю, речь пьяного с "дребезжанием" как-то мало ассоциируется, разве что произошло вторичное сближение с "дребезгом", породившее и "пьян вдребезги".

Впрочем, этимология "дребедени" не ясна, возможно на каком-то давнем уровне оно родственно дребезгу. А "дребезг" - это мелкие частицы чего-то, осколки, дробь. У кондитеров, например, "дребезг" - одна из стадий карамелизации сахара, когда он уже отлетает от воды мелкой дробью. Так что, в принципе, дребедень может быть суффиксальным образованием от дребезг, но очень давним, потерявшим связь с исходным "родственником".

Зюзя - действительно в некоторых говорах означало свинью. Но это вторично, "зюзя" - жидкая кашица, грязь. Именная эта грязная "зюзя" скорее всего и вошла в идиому - напрямую, а не посредством свиньи. Тому есть некоторое подтверждение в обороте "(мокрый) в зюзю" - о попавшем под дождь человеке. Тут уж свинья рядом не лежала.

Comment: @behemothus. У Пушкина в "Евгении Онегине": "Раз в настоящем упоеньи Он отличился, смело в грязь С коня калмыцкого свалясь, Как з ю з я пьяный, и французам Достался в плен: драгой залог!" ЗЮЗЯ мне встречалось и в нарицательном значении, типа как ТЁТЯ МОТЯ, ДЯДЯ ВАСЯ, ПАПАНДОПУЛО. Я помню советский худ. фильм (многосерийный) "Старая крепость" по одноимённой повести В.Беляева, - там один из героев (одессит) носил прозвище ЗЮЗЯ. Здесь намёк на еврея. Еврейское имя Сус-а/Шуш-а =(Сусан/а/, Сюзанна) в ополяченном виде звучало как Зузя. В русской разг. речи есть и другие "еврейские" намёки.

Comment: Про Онегена я знаю.  
Что из этого следует?  
А про еврейский след - не понял совершенно.   
Вы в Онегине предполагаете намек на еврея?  
Или полагаете, что пьян в Зюзю - это "пьян как еврей"?  
Я категорически отрицаю и то, и другое. С потока все взято.

Comment: @behemothus. Словосочетание ПЬЯНЫЙ ЗЮЗЯ содержит намёк на еврея точно также , как и словосочетания ЕТИШКИНА ЖИЗНЬ(МАТЬ) , ЁЖКИ(=ЁШКИН) КОТ , ШАРАШКИНА КОНТОРА , ЁРШ ТВОЮ МЕДЬ . Пушкин использовал этот жаргонизм . Что тут непонятного ?

Answer (score 0):

Есть выражение "вдрызг пьяный". Сочетание  [вдр] такое звучное, громкое. Вот словотворцы из народа  и придумали новое слово со значением  "вдрызг" - (в)драбадан. Такое происхождение слова вполне вероятно. Но это только моя версия.